# Javascript - Using Object literal with a number

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object:

```
var elObject = {
   one: {
    name: "Oliver"}
}
```

I can access name by doing elObject.one.name and everything is great, but let's say I have this instead:

```
var elObject = {
       1: {
        name: "Oliver"}
    }
```

Suddenly, I can't access name through elObject.1.name anymore since I'm using 1 instead of 'one'. Is there a a special escape or something I'm supposed to use with object literal and digits?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the plain object with number 1 using it as string. Once is not allowed to have a property name starting with number, you can access it using bracket notation.

Example and findle below.

```
var x = {
    '1' : {
        name: 'Joao'
    }
};
alert(x);
try {
    alert(x['1'].name);
}
catch(e){
    alert(e.message);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b4c34wLv/

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I changed the answer.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.

Comment: It was marked as duplicated after my answer.

Comment: It was marked as duplicate about 6 minutes before you posted your answer - timestamps don't lie :-) Maybe you've been subject to [one of the grace period bugs](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280668/1048572)